# Best Practice: Accessing instance of UIViewController from another in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a navigation controller with 4 view controllers on the stack. I need to access a function in ViewController1 from ViewController4. What is the proper way to do this?

1. Do I pass the reference to ViewController1 through ViewController2 & 3 then access the function using a protocol delegate?
2. Do I store a reference to ViewController1 in a struct then access it from there?

Number 2 is what I am currently doing. I set the reference when I leave ViewController1 then set that reference back to nil when I'm done with it.

Why I need to do this:

VC1 has a tableview with a bunch of items. The data in these items is edited in VC4. Once editing is done in VC4 I want to save, pop to root, and reload the tableview with the new data.

Comment: [Edit] your question with more specific details of why you need VC4 to access a function in VC1. Have a direct reference of one in the other is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plan is all wrong. What you should be doing is have a data model that can post notifications about changes in its data. There should be no link whatsoever between the view controllers. VC1 should be prepared to listen for notifications from the data model. When VC4 updates the data model, the data model will tell anyone that is listening that it has been updated.

With this setup, any number of view controller can all be listening to the same instance of the data model being passed around. Any part of your app can respond as needed to these notifications. The best part of this design is that no class has any knowledge of any other specific class except everyone knows about the data model.

The data model has no knowledge of any controllers or views.

No controllers have any direct link to other controllers except for one that needs to present another.

Comment: I am actually using a data model to handle my data. I have started implementing your suggestion using NotificationCenter and its seems to be what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use notification. Make VC1 to subscribe the notification. When need, in VC4, send the notification.